# Maximum Concurrency slots for a single user

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a user configured with mediumrc and a SQL Datawarehouse with 1500 DWU.

According to the docs:

- I can have a max of 32 concurrent queries
- I have 60 concurrent slots
- and the mediumrc uses 6 slots

I have only one user, which is responsible for the data ingestion of many tables.

Will I have a maximum of 10 concurrent queries for this user, considering it is the only thing running in the DW?

Comment: Which generation of Azure SQL Data Warehouse are you running?  [Static resource classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/resource-classes-for-workload-management#static-resource-classes) may also be worth a look for you.

Comment: Gen2: DW1500c
Why do static resource classes would be better for my case?

Comment: The ingestion wil have a different amount of data depending on the day and hour of the day. Sometimes we will have to perform the ingestion of a specific table and this table might be very large. These are the reasons why I opted to use the dynamic resource class.

Comment: Ah ok, it looked like it was a regular repeating thing from my original understanding and "Static resource classes are ideal if the data volume is known and constant" according to the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A max of 10 concurrent queries is the hypothetical maximum, yes [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/memory-concurrency-limits) for Gen 2 based on your scenario.  Certain operations (eg DDL) don't take concurrency slots so it may be you see slightly higher numbers but it will be there or thereabouts.

HTH

Comment: So, the concurrency is related to the session. If I open 10 sessions for the same mediumrc user. All of the queries are gonna process in parallel. Is that right?